# Flexbox not working on summary tags [Safari browser]

Tags: html, css, flexbox, safari

In Chrome, Firefox and the newest Safari browser I can use flexbox' `justify-content: space-between` on  summary tags:

https://codepen.io/dash/pen/qBZGRJe

```
align-items: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

```
<summary class=faq>
<h4>Heading</h4>
<svg viewBox="0 0 448 512" class=faq-icon><path fill="#000" d="M207.029 381.476L12.686 187.132c-9.373-9.373-9.373-24.569 0-33.941l22.667-22.667c9.357-9.357 24.522-9.375 33.901-.04L224 284.505l154.745-154.021c9.379-9.335 24.544-9.317 33.901.04l22.667 22.667c9.373 9.373 9.373 24.569 0 33.941L240.971 381.476c-9.373 9.372-24.569 9.372-33.942 0z"></path></svg>
</summary>
```

Older Safari browsers seem not to allow flexbox for `summary` tags and show the chevron icon under the heading.

Any ideas for a workaround on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `margin` property with auto-value on the flex-items to get the space between it.

Like this:

```css
.faq {
    align-items: center;
  background: #ccc;
    display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.faq-icon {
  height: 18px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<summary class=faq>
  <h4>Heading</h4>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 448 512" class=faq-icon><path fill="#000" d="M207.029 381.476L12.686 187.132c-9.373-9.373-9.373-24.569 0-33.941l22.667-22.667c9.357-9.357 24.522-9.375 33.901-.04L224 284.505l154.745-154.021c9.379-9.335 24.544-9.317 33.901.04l22.667 22.667c9.373 9.373 9.373 24.569 0 33.941L240.971 381.476c-9.373 9.372-24.569 9.372-33.942 0z"></path></svg>
</summary>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Best fit for my code situation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could try `position: absolute`:

```css
.faq {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.faq-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<summary class=faq>
  <h4>Heading</h4>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 448 512" class=faq-icon><path fill="#000" d="M207.029 381.476L12.686 187.132c-9.373-9.373-9.373-24.569 0-33.941l22.667-22.667c9.357-9.357 24.522-9.375 33.901-.04L224 284.505l154.745-154.021c9.379-9.335 24.544-9.317 33.901.04l22.667 22.667c9.373 9.373 9.373 24.569 0 33.941L240.971 381.476c-9.373 9.372-24.569 9.372-33.942 0z"></path></svg>
</summary>
```

Comment: Very nice, too! Thanks.